# Linq Query of ViewModel not DomainModel

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

When Looking through Google to find examples of using a MVC Crud setup, I always find that the detail page gets missed off as being important, Especially if you want to use a viewmodel.

The Problem I have is that the typical MVC Application setup from Visual Studio will use CRUD but the all the view pages will use a domain model not a view model.

So i want to pull data from two models based on the integer  easy if it's one model:

```
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Asset Assets = db.Assets.Find(id);

            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

But then how do i pull two sets? Here is my linq query on the viewmodel:

```
var ASSPATVM = (from s in db.Assets
                        join cp in db.PATs on s.AssetID equals cp.AssetID into AP
                        from subpat in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()


                        select new ASSPATVM
                        {
                            AssetID = s.AssetID,
                            ProductName = s.ProductName,
                            ModelName = s.ModelName,
                            SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                            ManufacturerName = s.ManufacturerName,
                            SerialNo = s.SerialNo,
                            PurchaseDate = s.PurchaseDate,
                            PoNo = s.PoNo,
                            Costing = s.Costing,
                            TeamName = s.TeamName,
                            StaffName = s.StaffName,
                            InspectionDocumnets = subpat.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                            InspectionOutcomeResult = subpat.InspectionOutcomeResult
                        });
```

**EDIT**

So I have tried:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? AssetID)
        {
            var ASSPATINCVM = (from s in db.Assets
                                  join cp in db.PATs on s.AssetID equals cp.AssetID into AP
                                  from subASSPAT in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        join ci in db.INSs on s.AssetID equals ci.AssetID into AI
                                        from subASSINC in AI.DefaultIfEmpty()


                                        select new ASSPATINCVM()
                                  {
                                      AssetID = s.AssetID,
                                      ProductName = s.ProductName,
                                      ModelName = s.ModelName,
                                      SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                                      ManufacturerName = s.ManufacturerName,
                                      SerialNo = s.SerialNo,
                                      PurchaseDate = s.PurchaseDate,
                                      PoNo = s.PoNo,
                                      Costing = s.Costing,
                                      TeamName = s.TeamName,
                                      StaffName = s.StaffName,
                                      WarrantyEndDate = subASSPAT.WarrantyEndDate,
                                      InspectionDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDate,
                                      InspectionOutcomeResult = subASSPAT.InspectionOutcomeResult,
                                      InspectionDocumnets = subASSPAT.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                                      InspectionDueDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDueDate
                                        });

            return View(ASSPATINCVM);
        }
```

I get the error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM'.
```

So then I tried to List()

```
InspectionDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDate,
                                      InspectionOutcomeResult = subASSPAT.InspectionOutcomeResult,
                                      InspectionDocumnets = subASSPAT.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                                      InspectionDueDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDueDate
                                        }).List();

@model List<Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM>
```

But now the complaint is

```
List<ASSPATINCVM>' does not contain a definition for 'ModelName'
```

**Update**

The ViewModel:

```
using Assets.Models;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Assets.Areas.CCS.Models
{
    public class ASSPATINCVM
    {


        public int AssetID { get; set; }
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public string PoNo { get; set; }
        public float? Costing { get; set; }
        public string InspectionDocumnets { get; set; }

        public Product ProductName { get; set; }
        public InspectionOutcome InspectionOutcomeResult { get; set; }
        public Model ModelName { get; set; }
        public BudgetCode Code { get; set; }
        public AssetType AssetTypeName { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        public Staff StaffName { get; set; }
        public Team TeamName { get; set; }
        public Supplier SupplierName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WarrantyEndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InspectionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InspectionDueDate { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Part of the Details Page:

```
@model Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>ClinicalAsset</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModelName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetTypeName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
```

Comment: Can you provide your View code as well? It seems like you have a reference to ModelName on the list, not on an item within.

Comment: @jcruz Just Updated

Comment: my current error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on jcruz answer:

I also needed to add a link between the id and AssetID as such:

```
var ASSPATINCVM = (from s in db.Assets
                                       join cp in db.PATs on s.AssetID equals cp.AssetID into AP
                                       from subASSPAT in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       join ci in db.INSs on s.AssetID equals ci.AssetID into AI
                                       from subASSINC in AI.DefaultIfEmpty()


                                       select new ASSPATINCVM
                                       {
                                           AssetID = s.AssetID,
                                           AssetTypeName = s.AssetTypeName,
                                           ProductName = s.ProductName,
                                           ModelName = s.ModelName,
                                           SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                                           ManufacturerName = s.ManufacturerName,
                                           SerialNo = s.SerialNo,
                                           PurchaseDate = s.PurchaseDate,
                                           PoNo = s.PoNo,
                                           Costing = s.Costing,
                                           TeamName = s.TeamName,
                                           StaffName = s.StaffName,
                                           WarrantyEndDate = subASSPAT.WarrantyEndDate,
                                           InspectionDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDate,
                                           InspectionOutcomeResult = subASSPAT.InspectionOutcomeResult,
                                           InspectionDocumnets = subASSPAT.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                                           InspectionDueDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDueDate
                                       }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssetID == id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller action is returning an `IEnumerable<ASSPATINCVM>` but your view is expecting a single instance of `ClinicalASSPATINCVM`, see this line in your view:

```
@model Assets.Areas.Clinical.Models.ClinicalASSPATINCVM
```

You should be able to update your view to the corresponding `IEnumerable` type for your model class of `ASSPATINCVM`, and then iterate through your list, similar to this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Assets.Areas.CCS.Models.ASSPATINCVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>ClinicalAsset</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    @foreach(var m in Model)
    {
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].ModelName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @m.ModelName
        </dd>
    }
    </dl>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, you'll need to update your query to return a single instance of `ASSPATINCVM`, which you can do this way:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? AssetID)
    {
        var ASSPATINCVM = (from s in db.Assets
                              join cp in db.PATs on s.AssetID equals cp.AssetID into AP
                              from subASSPAT in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    join ci in db.INSs on s.AssetID equals ci.AssetID into AI
                                    from subASSINC in AI.DefaultIfEmpty()


                                    select new ASSPATINCVM()
                              {
                                  AssetID = s.AssetID,
                                  ProductName = s.ProductName,
                                  ModelName = s.ModelName,
                                  SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                                  ManufacturerName = s.ManufacturerName,
                                  SerialNo = s.SerialNo,
                                  PurchaseDate = s.PurchaseDate,
                                  PoNo = s.PoNo,
                                  Costing = s.Costing,
                                  TeamName = s.TeamName,
                                  StaffName = s.StaffName,
                                  WarrantyEndDate = subASSPAT.WarrantyEndDate,
                                  InspectionDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDate,
                                  InspectionOutcomeResult = subASSPAT.InspectionOutcomeResult,
                                  InspectionDocumnets = subASSPAT.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                                  InspectionDueDate = subASSPAT.InspectionDueDate
                                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(ASSPATINCVM);
    }
```

Comment: I do only want to see the details of the single ID not to go through lists.of all the ID's in a table. Does that matter ?

Comment: In that case, you should update your controller action query to return a single item. You can use the `Single` or `First` LINQ methods to get only one item. Then your view would remain as is, since its not a collection.

Comment: @microchef I've updated my answer to include an example of your change to the controller action.